# How do I create animated waves in a square box using css?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have been trying to figure out how to create some smooth animated waves in a 200x200 pixel box that come from the top. I haven't been able to get a good result. All my attempts result in a spiky wave effect.

An example that I have trying to tweak is [here](https://csspoints.com/css-wave-effect-responsive-design/)

This one is at the bottom of the page. I am trying to put it in a box, make the base of the waves start at the top and makes the waves meet the bottom of the box. I could really use some help creating this effect.

Comment: Can you explain what actual you, need with pictures?

Comment: @Awais I can try to make a mock-up and get back to you with a link.